# What rule of linear algebra makes this vector valued function f multiplied by vector x to transpose the vector x?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, vectors

The problem is:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \epsilon}\bigg[g\big(\frac{f(x+\epsilon)}{f(x)}\big)f'(x)\bigg]$$
function $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+ $
function $f: \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ for $d>1$, therefore $x$, $\epsilon$ and  $f'(a)$ are (column) vectors;  $x, \epsilon, f'(a) \in \mathbb{R}^d$

I derived that:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \epsilon}g\big(\frac{f(x+\epsilon)}{f(x)}\big) = g'\big(\frac{f(x+\epsilon)}{f(x)}\big)\frac{f'(x+\epsilon)}{f(x)}I$$
where $I $ is identity matrix. Notice that this quantity is also a $d$-dimensional (column) vector.

Now I assume that the complete solution is a matrix:
$$g'\big(\frac{f(x+\epsilon)}{f(x)}\big)\frac{f'(x+\epsilon)}{f(x)} f'^{\boldsymbol{\color{red}\top}}(x)$$

**But according to what fact of linear algebra does the last transposition happen**? From the [matrix cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) (equation 37):
$$\partial(AB) = \partial(A)B + A\partial(B)$$

as $f'(x)$ is constant, the second term of sum is another identity matrix $I$, and but the fist term is no transposition!

Thank you for clarification!

Comment: If we're going to compute according first linear algebra principles then you have the derivatives being the wrong dimensions. The derivative of a scalar w.r.t. a column vector is always a row vector. This makes the math work out as well.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer!. So if I understand correctly $f'(a)$ is everywhere a row vector (which I now see makes sense, as in the second equation I have to multiply with $I$ from the right side).$f'^{\top}(a)$  is then a column vector. But then this whole expression would be a scalar, not a matrix! I am still trying to de-confuse myself...

Comment: $vv^T$ is a matrix, not a scalar. It is the outer product.

Comment: "The derivative of a scalar w.r.t. a column vector is always a row vector."  $f(a)$ is scalar, $a$ is a column vector, therefore $f'(a)$ is a row vector. $f'^{\top}(a)$ is a column vector. $\frac{\partial}{\partial \epsilon}g\big(\frac{f(x+\epsilon)}{f(x)}\big)$ is a row vector. Is this right?